# TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, enumerate

I am getting an error when running my code.  After reviewing similar error codes from others questions in Stack overflow,  I altered by code by using square brackets after correct_code=list[]  and I am still getting the error. The funny thing is that this code ran perfectly on Friday and I did not touch it over the weekend.

I am doing QAQC with with several csv each contain a list of alphanumeric species codes.

```
Original code:
#create an array for the flagged codes to be placed
species_not_in_state = []

#make a list of the species which are found in the state   
correct_code=list(set(fire_species_code).intersection(set(state_species_code)))


#for codes which are not found in that state make a second list
for item in fire_species_code:
    if item not in correct_code:
        species_not_in_state.append(item)
print(species_not_in_state)
```

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      3 
      4 #make a list of the species which are found in the state
----> 5 correct_code=list[set(fire_species_code).intersection(set(state_species_code))]
      6 
      7

TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not callable

```
Dataset headers:
Fire_species_code:
0    AGFR
1    AGFR
2    AGFR
3    AGFR
4    AGFR
Name: Species, dtype: object

State_species_code
0    ACARO2  
1     ACSC5
2     ACSC5
3     ACSC5
4     ACSC5
Name: Symbol, dtype: object
```

Comment: In your code list is called as function list().
But in the error message list is used as list[...]
So check your code again.

Comment: I get the same error regardless:                                                                                             ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-c466196d14a7> in <module>()
      3 
      4 #make a list of the species which are found in the state
----> 5 correct_code=list(set(fire_species_code).intersection(set(state_species_code)))
      6 
      7 

TypeError: 'enumerate' object is not callable

Comment: Show me how the data fire_species_code and state_species_code look like.

Comment: I added the headers from the the fire_species_code and state-species_code.  Not sure if that was the best way, I am new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Try set(fire_species_code) & set(state_species_code)

Comment: reran this: correct_code=set(fire_species_code) & set(state_species_code)   returned the same error code.  I also tried

Comment: I also tried: correct_code=set(fire_species_code) and set(state_species_code)

Comment: Do you know where I can read about enumerated objects?  Ive been googling the error code with no luck.

Comment: You have used pandas DataFrame. For single column data this is overkill. Anyway, if this is DataFrame you need to extract the column.

set(fire_species_code['Species']) & set(state_species_code['Symbol'])

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question here: https://wizpert.com/wizdom/python-object-is-not-callable-error

Apparently my variable name was already used. Cell>All Output>Clear did not fix it, I had tried that before posting my question.

Kernel>Restart & clear all output>Restart and clear all outputs fixed my problem.